# What is the behavior of "WillReplace" in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation, you can set `WillReplace` for an update policy.

```yaml
UpdatePolicy:
  AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
    WillReplace: Boolean
```

Does it refer to replacing the Autoscaling group with a new one, or replacing the instances in the Auto scaling group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) write that it replaces **ASG** itself. This means, instances will be also replaced:

> Specifies whether an **Auto Scaling group and the instances** it contains are replaced during an update.